# facebook application update

Tags: php, api, facebook

I developed a simple application on Facebook using PHP and I want to know how the people can add this application, and after adding the application a update is generated (e.g vipin join this application).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Users don't add applications anymore.  The closest they can get is bookmarking, which your application receives no notice of.  The closest thing you can get to checking as a developer is checking is [Users.isAppUser](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.isAppUser).

You also don't receive notice when a user grants/rejects permissions (which is generally a prerequisite to viewing your application).

Basically, you have to [post notices](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Notifications.send) and [create feed entires](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Feed.publishUserAction) in direct response to user action (unless they've granted you a perpetual session).

The old model of actually adding applications was all kinds of broken from a user experience point-of-view, so Facebook basically pulled the plug on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, no more "Dude just added this app" messages in the newsfeed. However, Facebook will occasionally show "Dude uses the 'Thing' application" messages under the "highlights" section of a user's homepage. There's nothing you can do to encourage or discourage it -- it just happens.